# Facebook Graph API upgrade to 2.6 causing auth failure

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to upgrade Facebook Graph API version from 2.5 to 2.6 
with  changing the auth endpoint from "oauth/device" to "device/login" and getting following response

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#191) redirect_uri is not owned by the application.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 191,
        "error_data": {
            "name": "redirect_uri"
        },
        "fbtrace_id": "FPupgVUcj/I"
    }
}
```

I have checked on the backend settings of my app, redirect uri is superset of saved Website uri there.

Comment: It doesn’t want “supersets”, it wants the _exact_ redirect URIs your app uses.

Comment: Hi CBroe, I am elaborating using exmaple, if WebSite uri is "www.abc.com/ ", then my redirect uri is "www.abc.com/facebook_success.html", which is as per facebook guidelines as per my understanding.

Comment: _“if WebSite url is www.abc.com/”_ - then what?

Comment: @CBroe , please check my latest comment.

Comment: First of all, the redirect URI is whatever your app specifies/generates. (`https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html` exists for desktop apps using webviews, but that has nothing whatsoever to do with your website app.) You need to go an find out what value is actually used, and then input that exact URL in the app settings.

Comment: I am using exact uri during rest call which is mentioned under field "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" of app settings, As I had perviously mentioned also value for field "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" contains value for "
Site URL" field in app settings.

Comment: When exactly do you get this error message, which part of the process? It looks like the response to an API request, not like the error message that would be shown to the user on the actual login dialog.

Comment: Hi @CBroe , as per 2nd step REST call at section "implement Login for Devices" on page "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/for-devices" , i have made the call, with valid parameters and getting this response